# Trigger event during a css transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I want to add a class / set a custom z-index during a css transition.
In my researches, I didn't find anything except `webkitTransitionEnd` which don't do the work.

I have an animated div on hover but if I hover multiple div, he go below the other, that's why I want to set a custom class during the transition (not during the hover).

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Fvdb/) (simplified for webkit)

and the problem in image
[image]

Edit: The real problem is when I hover a div, unhover, rehover, hover an other, so it's hard to do a simple timeout...

Comment: Why don't you trigger the transition with javascript, then you can easily add the z-index, set an timeout with your transition duration and set the z-index back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you "un-hover", the switch to the original z-index is happening instantaneously.  So the rotating panel is no longer painted in front of its neighbours.

The easiest way to solve that is to make sure that the z-index value is being transitioned as well.  It wasn't transitioning in your code as you had it, because z-index was being set on the parent `div.panel` but your transition functions were only applied to the child `div.front` and `div.back`.

This seems to work even when you switch between panels mid-transition:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Fvdb/1/

```
.panel{
  transition: z-index 1s;
}
```

(Note that I've commented-out the z-index values on the individual panel faces for simplicity; it doesn't seem to change anything either way on Chrome, haven't tested elsewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

I would give for granted that the CSS transition will succeed, and just remove the class after a timeout equal to the transition time:

with a transition of 2s:

```
.panel {
   transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

set this timeout to remove the class after 2000 ms:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //you remove the class after the transition time
    $('.panel').removeClass("transition-running");
},2000)

$('.panel')
     //you add the class before changing the style
    .addClass("transition-running")    
    .css("opacity","0.1");
```

Comment: My main problem is if you hover : the transition start. If you unhover during that transition, the transition goes back, so a timer mean nothing, the duration of the flip depend on the duration time of the hover

Comment: Maybe you can use the hover event to add class. I'll try to edit the fiddle

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not showing the effect you showed in the picture... has you changed the effect you are using?

Comment: It's from the same fiddle, just hover to trigger the transition and move the mouse back (you have < 1sec :)

Comment: Yes, but the 3d effect showed in the picture it's not working. I'm using chrome on Ubuntu

Comment: Hmmm strange, it should work for webkit. Thanks for pointing this out, I will check that before putting it in production